# what is the proper way to free up memory from crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i just want know what is the proper way to release memory that was occupied by crystal report.

this is my code :

```
 ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
            try
            {
                reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/EndUser/PostHistoryReport.rpt"));
                reportdocument.SetDataSource(myDataSet);
                reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "user123");
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reportdocument != null)
                {
                    reportdocument.Close();
                    ((IDisposable)reportdocument).Dispose();
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to release the memory when the page where CrystalReportViewer1 is placed is closed. Put your report document in a session variable and close and dispose it when the page is closed.